# Php показывает ошибки от функций начинающихся с '@'

Tags: php, php-fpm

Хоть в php документации и написано:

> PHP поддерживает один оператор управления ошибками: знак @. В случае,
>   если он предшествует какому-либо выражению в PHP-коде, любые сообщения
>   об ошибках, генерируемые этим выражением, будут проигнорированы.

Но в Sentry всё-равно вижу ошибку при вызове команды:

```
if(($time=@filemtime($cacheFile))>time())
```

> filemtime(): stat failed for
>   /var/www/vhosts/test/protected/runtime/cache/ab95017da94ec0c0561b66fa964ef3b7.bin

Каким образом сказать php всё-таки вести себя ожидаемо - не показывать ошибки от функций начинающихся с '@'?

Comment: 1. Какая версия Sentry 2. Могут-ли быть еще обработчики ошибок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подавление ошибок операцией `@` в первую очередь касается встроенных средств логирования. Чтобы это работало для обработчика, установленного через `set_error_handler()` необходимо чтобы сам обработчик это поддерживал.

См. [описание `set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php)

> Пользовательский обработчик будет вызываться при любой ошибке, независимо от настроек, заданных функцией error_reporting(). Однако, вы можете прочитать текущее значение error_reporting и задать в обработчике соответствующие действия. В частности, это значение будет равно 0, если выражение, вызвавшее ошибку, начинается с оператора контроля ошибок @.

Наверное Sentry этого не делает.